# Understanding Correctness of Bidirectional Dijkstra

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms, correctness-proof

I'm trying to understand the correctness of the bidirectional version of Dijkstras algorithm as mentioned here on slide 10:

https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr06/cos423/Handouts/EPP%20shortest%20path%20algorithms.pdf

For a contradiction, they consider an $s-t$ path $p$ that is shorter than the minimum sum $\mu$ of tentative distances from the forward and backward search.
The next step I don't understand: there is an edge $(v,w)$ on this path, such that:

1. $dist(s,v) < top_f$
2. $dist(w,t) < top_b$

Where do these relationships come from?

From what I see, after stopping, it holds that $\mu \leq top_f + top_b$.

So if we consider any edge $(v,w)$ of $p$, we have that

$dist(s,v) + length(v,w) + dist(w,t) < top_f + top_b$

We can leave out that edge to get the inequality

$dist(s,v) + dist(w,t) < top_f + top_b$

But from this, I can't derive these two relationships.

I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: Here's some thought: Consider the order of removal of distances from the min-heap - smaller partial distances are removed first. Then if $\text{dist}(s,v)>top_f$, $top_f$ would have been removed first, which results in a contradiction.

Comment: @BearAqua I've added an answer with a proof that is easier to understand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across these [slides](http://rtime.felk.cvut.cz/~hanzalek//KO/SPT_e.pdf) where on slide 23 another proof is given, however the idea of this proof is the same as in the slides of my original post.

[image]

But this still doesn't show, why $dist(s,v)$ and $dist(w,t)$ need to be less than $top_f$ and $top_b$ respectively.

EDIT: Note that with this proof $dist(s,v) \leq top_f$ and $dist(w,t) \leq top_b$ hold, since both vertices have already been settled. I'm in doubt, whether the original statement $dist(s,v) < top_f$ and $dist(w,t) < top_b$ is actually correct and therefore I'm marking this question as 'answered'. However if anyone finds an explanation, feel free to answer!